# C++ Hide enum class from rest of code

Tags: c++, c++14, enum-class

I have some code with an `enum class` in it. I only want there to exist a single instance of this enum class. I am aware of singleton classes, but is there a way to make an enum class only visible from within the current file?

Trivial example:

```
enum class StateInstanceOption
{
    STATE_INSTANCE_A,
    STATE_INSTANCE_B
}gCurrentState{StateInstanceOption::STATE_INSTANCE_A}; // global variable to hold current state "pointer" (really a flag)
```

Obviously the user need to be able to read/write `gCurrentState`, but I don't want the user to be able to create more instances of `StateInstanceOption`.

Is this possible?

To clarify, I don't want the user to be able to create another instance of `StateInstanceOption`, but I do want them to be able to see `gCurrentState`.

Comment: Did I miss the new C standard making C C++? If not: don't spam tags!

Comment: Make it `static` or put it in an unnamed namespace? Thus making it available to the current compilation unit only.?

Comment: I'm quite surprised this compiles, but it does.  It is however undreadable.

Comment: Why on earth would you want this? Behind the scenes, an enum is just an integer... How would you access (read) `gCurrentState` after all? You couldn't assign to it, if only a single "instance" was present, wouldn't you?

Comment: @DanielJour `gCurrentState` would be read in the current file only.